# fail to set image from gallery to set the imageview

Tags: android, imageview, gallery, android-manifest

i successfully set the image from gallery to the image view yesterday,without changing any code,but it failed today,and the only problem i think is the manifest

Here is my manifest,thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test1"
android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: may be your friend messed up your code :D :D.Your manifest is perfect.

Comment: @VipulShah lol hope so,is there any possibility about my level and version of my phone?

Comment: @VipulShah just thought of one possibility,is there anything do with the SDcard,cuz SD card doesn't sometimes